# How to find and replace using std::regex_replace() function in cpp

Tags: c++, regex

I am working on a project where I need to find words starting with **$<** and ending with **>$** and replace with it with a word stored in a variable.

Example

```
string a ="hello";
string b = "Fellow $<world>$, full of $<smart>$ people"
std::cout<<std::regex_replace(b, "\\b($<)([^ ]*)(>$)\\b", a); //should print "Fellow hello, full of hello people"
```

but seems like this is not possible directly.

How can I work around this?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: I cannot specify the string with which I want to replace the expression that I found. In cpp I cannot use the function regex_replace() as i have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Then why are you giving `regex_replace()` as an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is fine with the exception of 2 points:

- Regex - you have unescaped `$` that means *end of string*, `\b` word boundary before and after `$` that requires a word character to appear right next to the `$` symbol.
- There is no signature for `regex_replace` like the one you used.

So, the correct regex is

```
\$<[^<>]*>\$
```

The `\$` matches a literal `$`, then follows a literal `<`, then 0 or more characters other than `<` and `>` up to the literal `>$`.

In C++, you can use raw strings (`R"()"`) to declare regex objects, it will relieve the pain of escaping metacharacters twice.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/wfOHxy):

```
string a ="hello";
string b = "Fellow $<world>$, full of $<smart>$ people";
std::cout<<std::regex_replace(b, std::regex(R"(\$<[^<>]*>\$)"), a);
```

Output: `Fellow hello, full of hello people`

Comment: I am accepting this answer because my problem was I was not using **R** while defining my regular expression for which I was getting runtime error.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple problems here. First, `regex_replace` takes a `basic_regex` as the second parameter. Second, it doesn't perform the replace in-place, but returns a new string. Finally, you have some unnecessary parenthesis in your regular expression. So your code should look like this:

```
string input = "well, $<hello>$ there!";
std::regex reg("\\$<.+>\\$");
// prints "well, fellow there!":
std::cout << '\n' << std::regex_replace(input, reg, "fellow") << '\n';
```

Note that word boundary check (`\\b`) is not going to work here because the start and end characters of the sequence are dollar signs, and `\\b` marks *word* boundary, which means either

- The beginning of a word (current character is a letter, digit, or underscore, and the previous character is not)
- The end of a word (current character is not a letter, digit, or underscore, and the previous character is one of those)

Comment: Don't you need to escape those dollar signs, e.g. `\\b\$<.+>\$\\b` ?

Comment: @Tim, That depends on the grammar chosen, and in this case it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: Fair enough.   I guess every language has its own particular way of doing regex.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, actually I've just tested both ways and there seems to be no difference, though the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/ecmascript) says it should mean "end of line" if un-escaped. I'll add the note to the answer.

Comment: I would default to using standard regex conventions as a rule, though I don't doubt your C++ code ^ ^

Comment: I'm not all sure what you are trying to accoumplish here. But my requirement is take input `well, <$hello$> there!` and  `fellow`, and output is `well, fellow there!`

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall~ Thanks for your time sir. +1 for you too. I realised where I made mistake. I was missing **R** for which I was getting the runtime error. Check @stribizhev's response.